# Changing a div's opacity when the user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a website and I want the header (named floatHeader in my code) to be invisible at the start and then becomes visible once you start to scroll. I have tried my best to do it with JQuery but I'm not very experienced, so any advice would be much appreciated.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fZGqc/1/) is the current code that I have.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) { 
        $('.floatHeader').css("opacity", 1);
    }
    else{
        $('.floatHeader').css("opacity", 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: You want the header to be visible when the user scrolls down..? then it won't be visible to the user since he already scrolled down, right? doesn't make sense to me..

Answer (score 5):

Your code is working fine. You just need to include jQuery to your page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is your **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/fZGqc/2/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You missed to `load` any version of `jquery`

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/fZGqc/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have missed adding jquery in your fiddle code. So add jquery file in your code in  tag like this.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Also If you want the header to be invisible at start then set the "style:display:none;" in your header. This will hide your header at start.

```
<div class="header" style="display:none"></div>
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZGqc/6/).

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use the jquery plugin.

here is the link: http://stickyjs.com/